# How to close safari tabs by url using applescript

Tags: macos, tabs, safari, applescript

I'm looking for a way to close specific tabs in safari by the url. 
I would probably expand on something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        tell t
            if name starts with "google.com" then close
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

the problem here is that i haven't found a way how to get the url value of a tab and close them based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the URL from Safari based on the active tab.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set w to first window
    set t to current tab of w
    display dialog (URL of t as string)
end tell
```

And then you could iterate over every tab/page like this :

```
tell application "Safari"
    set windowCount to number of windows
        repeat with x from 1 to windowCount
            set tabCount to number of tabs in window x
            repeat with y from 1 to tabCount
                set thistab to tab y of window x
                set foo to URL of thistab
                if foo is not equal to "bar" then close thistab
           end repeat
       end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: This won't work because "set foo to name of thistab" will not match a URL.

Comment: You're right, I edited the code : `set foo to URL of thistab`

Comment: `count of tabs of window i` gives me an error "Safari got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000".

Comment: the final version that i ended up using:
`tell application "Google Chrome"
 set windowList to every tab of every window whose (URL contains "skype.com")
 repeat with tabList in windowList
  repeat with thistab in tabList
   close thistab
  end repeat
 end repeat
end tell
tell application "Safari"
 set windowList to every tab of every window whose (URL contains "skype.com")
 repeat with tabList in windowList
  repeat with thistab in tabList
   close thistab
  end repeat
 end repeat
end tell`

Comment: You should edit your first post with your solution, rather than commenting here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method:

```
set closeURLs to {"http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.apple.com"}

repeat with theURL in closeURLs
    tell application "Safari" to close (every tab of every window whose URL contains (contents of theURL))
end repeat
```

Comment: for me it does compile but does nothing when I run it. Doesn't seem to matter if the url from closeURLs is a partial or an exact match either. Any ideas? If it helps, I'm using safari 6.0.5 on osx 10.8.4.

Comment: It works for me in Snow Leopard and 10.8.4 Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1)